# How to pass variables to another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 variable in the main activity. i need to pass these variable values to the next activity.how can i do it?

```
   button.Click += delegate {
   var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
   activity2.PutExtra ("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
   StartActivity (activity2);
};
```

Comment: What is type of those two variables?
You can send any number of variables with Intent.putExtra() 
and get them in new activity onCreate() by Intent.getExtra()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 5):

create and object of intent and send your data throw putstring() or putExtra() methods

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
 intent.putString("key1", var1);// if its string type
 Intent.putExtra("key2", var2);// if its int type
 startActivity(intent);
```

on receiving side

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String var1 = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
int i = var2.getIntExtra("key2", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Send data from `MainActivity` to `Activity2` using:**

```
Intent activity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
activity2.PutExtra("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
StartActivity(activity2);
```

**Receive data in `Activity2` using:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ..............
    ..................

    if( getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        String myData = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyData");
    }

    ...............
    .....................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FirstActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Example.class); 
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
intent.putExtras(mBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondACtivity

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass you values in bundle also

FirstActivity.java

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class); 
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
startActivity(mIntent )
```

SecondActivity.java

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.

I think this will help you..

Answer (score -1):

You can make this with a static variable.

MainActivity.java

```
public static String nameVariable= "Text";
```

SecondActivity.java

```
String textFromMainActivity = MainActivity.nameVariable;
```